# Testing an angular controller with a service dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am attempting to create a very simple unit test for an angular controller however I am finding a lot of different information with regards to mocking a service giving different approaches with a majority of the examples revolving around the dependency being $http.

I have a very basic service for managing 'bugs' within my app, it essentially provides a basic API for local storage management.

My controller looks like:

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('bugTrackerApp.controllers', []);

app.controller('App', ['$scope', 'bugsAPI', function ($scope, bugsAPI) {

    $scope.addBug = function()
    {
        bugsAPI.addBug($scope.bug);
        $scope.setEmptyBug();
    }

    $scope.setEmptyBug = function(){
        $scope.bug = {};
        $scope.bug.status = 1;
        $scope.bug.assignee = null;
        $scope.bug.dateAdded = new Date();
    }

    $scope.setEmptyBug();
}]);
```

The test I have created looks like:

```
describe('Controllers', function(){

var scope, controller, mockBugsAPI;

beforeEach(module('bugTrackerApp.controllers', function($provide){

    mockBugsAPI = jasmine.createSpyObj('bugsAPI', ['addBug']);

    $provide.value('bugsAPI', mockBugsAPI);

}));

describe('App Controller', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        controller = $controller('App', {
            '$scope': scope
        });

    }));

    it('should be defined....', function() {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should define a bug....', function() {
        expect(scope.bug).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should set defaults on the initialised bug....', function() {
        expect(scope.bug.status).toBe(1);
        expect(scope.bug.assignee).toBe(null);
        expect(scope.bug.dateAdded instanceof Date).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should be able to add a bug....', function() {
        scope.addBug(scope.bug);
        expect(mockBugsAPI.addBug).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

});

Is this a good approach? I create a spy object of the service and then use $provide to make sure this spy object is injected instead of the real service.

Comment: So, the code above is working and you just want to know if there is any better alternative?

Comment: Nope it fails because bugsAPI doesn't exists, I cant work out how I should be mocking it.

Comment: You could use the [jasmine.createSpyObj](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>) to create a mock instance of your service.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do that based on my code snippet above? How will that handle the 3rd party dependencies my service has such as localstorage too?

Comment: That depends on what you want to test. If it just that you want to test if the controller interract with the bugsAPI properly regardless of the real implementation of the bugsAPI. You shouldn't care about the 3rd party dependencies. Just mock all methods of bugsAPI to immediately return predefined data.

Comment: Yep as you say I just want to test that the controller interacts with the API correctly. This is another area where I get confused as some examples people use the real service with createSpyObj and others manually create a completely fake api object inside their test.

Comment: If you want a concrete example, please show your controller code where it use the bugsAPI service.

Comment: Added controller code

Comment: I've just copied your code into a plunker and it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/QTUsDZC5FhooaNZCGgSR?p=preview I will include some example later to help you get started.

Comment: Hello, I have gotten a little further, do you think the approach I have for my test looks correct?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine. Seems like I needn't to show you an example anymore :)